# Testing if A range is completely empty in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check to see if any cell in a specified range has data in it so that I can move onto the next step of the project and print out the data if it does. Let's say that I have a range A1:F39, how would I check to see if there was any data in any of these cells? At the moment I loop through the entire range of cells one by one, going through the entire row before I change to the next column, and seeing if the cell is blank. If there is a better way to do this I would appreciate all of the help, thank you!

```
Dim RowCounter As Integer
Dim ColumnTraversing As Integer
Dim PopulatedCounter As Integer 
RowCounter = 1
ColumnTraversing = 1
PopulatedCounter = 0
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test") 
   While (ColumnTraversing <= 6)'column looper

       While (RowCounter < 40) 'Row Looper
'
       If (.Cells(RowCounter, ColumnTraversing).Text <> "") Then
           i = i + 1
       End If
       RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
       Wend

   ColumnTraversing = ColumnTraversing + 1
   RowCounter = 1
    Wend
    If (i > 0) Then 
        PopulatedCounter = PopulatedCounter + 1
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Why not just use, say, `COUNTA(A1:F39)` and if it's greater than 0, then it's not empty?

Comment: ^^^^  `If Application.CountA(.Range("A1:F39"))>0 Then`

Comment: Today is the day that I learned Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA is a thing, I spent a good amount of time trying to find that I guess I just never worded it correctly. Thank you for your help!